# Sort product data from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have two tables. The first:

```
Products table:

+----+-----------+
| id | name      | 
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Product 1 |
|  2 | Product 2 |
|  3 | Product 3 |
+----+-----------+
```

This contains product names and other table contains prices for different product variants:

```
Products prices table:

+-----+------------+-------------+
| id  | product_id | price       |
+-----+------------+-------------+
|  5  | 1          |  12.00      | 
|  6  | 1          |  32.00      | 
|  11 | 1          |  56.00      | 
|  14 | 2          |  11         | 
|  44 | 3          |  12         |
+-----+------------+-------------+
```

I need to create a sort on price (lowest and highest)

Comment: Absolutely possible. What did you tried?

Comment: just looping in php and than sort arrays

Comment: And you've tried nothing with SQL till now? With Joins, Sorts, group by etc?

Comment: Write SQL query and order by price ASC or DESC... Also how can you give different price for same product id?

Comment: `SELECT p.\`name\` as Name, v.\`price\` as Price FROM \`Products\` p LEFT JOIN \`Prices\` v ON v.\`product_id\` = p.\`id\` ORDER BY v.\`price\` DESC;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, for this you have to use **JOIN** and **ORDER BY** clause.

Ex:

```
select t1.id, t2.product_id t2.price FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.pid ORDER BY t2.price
```

[Mysql join with order by reference guide](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/joining-with-group-by-and-order-by.php)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Query:

```
 select t1.[id],t1.[name],t2.[price]
 from [yourtable1] t1
 Join [yourtable2] t2 on
 t1.[id]=t2.[product_id]
 Order by t2.[price] Asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code...

```
 SELECT product_tbl.name, product_tbl.id, product_price.product_id, product_price.price FROM product_tbl, product_price WHERE product_tbl.id=product_price.product_id ORDER BY product_price.price DESC;
```