# Sort products prices from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

What is the way to sort a MYSQL result from multiple tables?

I have two tables. The first:

"store_products" table:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      | 
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Product 1 |
|  2 | Product 2 |
|  3 | Product 3 |
+----+-----------+
```

Here i placed product names. Other table contains prices for different product variants:

"store_products_variants" table:

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
| id  | product_id | price_sale  | ordering    |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
|  5  | 1          |  06.00      | 2           |
|  6  | 1          |  32.00      | 3           |
|  11 | 1          |  56.00      | 1           |
|  14 | 2          |  09.00      | 1           |
|  44 | 3          |  15.00      | 1           |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to create a sort on price (lowest and highest), that uses only first variant - ordered by column "ordering" from "store_products_variants" table.

From example above, the results should be:

```
+---+------------+---------------+
| 1 | Product 2  | (price 09.00) |
| 3 | Product 3  | (price 15.00) |
| 2 | Product 1  | (price 56.00) |
+---+------------+---------------+
```

Is this possible in MySQL?

Comment: You can achieve it by using `JOIN`. [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: I tried SELECT p.`name` as Name, p.`id` as id, .v.`price_sale` as Price FROM `store_products` p LEFT JOIN `store_products_variants` v ON v.`product_id` = p.`id` ORDER BY v.`price_sale` ASC. But is taking all variants

Comment: What is the first column in your result displaying? 1, 3, 2 looks a little random

Comment: So where ordering = 1. Come on. Try something

Comment: what's the purpose of the ordering column

Comment: first ordering is not always 1. It can be different.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342642/sort-product-data-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql. Please do not double-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ordering` column to join the correct variant onto the product.

This would be the query if the correct `ordering` value was always the 1.

```
SELECT 
    products.name,
    variants.price_sale
FROM store_products AS products
INNER JOIN store_products_variants AS variants
    ON variants.product_id = products.id 
    AND variants.ordering = 1
ORDER BY variants.price_sale ASC
```

This query will first look for the lowest `ordering` value of a product. Then use it to join the price on your result:

```
SELECT
    products.name,
    variants.price_sale
FROM
    store_products AS products
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        product_id,
        MIN(ordering) AS ordering
    FROM
        store_products_variants
    GROUP BY
        product_id
) AS variantOrdering
    ON variantOrdering.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN store_products_variants AS variants 
    ON variants.product_id = variantOrdering.product_id
    AND variants.ordering = variantOrdering.ordering
ORDER BY 
    variants.price_sale ASC
```

Comment: the problem is the first "ordering" is not always 1

Comment: Yeah well, that's something we need to know :p So it is simply the lowest ordering value? There should be some criteria, otherwise we would have to guess.

Comment: almost working :) Do you have any idea how to get only product_variant with  lowest ordering?

Comment: You're welcome :). Can you please accept / upvote the answer if it was helpful? It's the Stackoverflow-way of saying thanks, also others quickly see if your problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.* from(
select t1.[id], t1.[name], 
'(price ' + cast(max(t2.[price_sale]) as varchar(50)) + ')' as [price]
from [#store_products] t1
left join [#store_products_variants] t2
on t1.[id] = t2.[]product_id
group by t1.[id], t1.[name]
)t
Order by len(t.[price]), t.[price];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Try to use the JOIN command, and JOIN on the ID of each table.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is possible please use this query

```
SELECT p.id,p.name,spv.price_sale
 from products p 
    INNER JOIN store_products_variants spv ON spv.product_id = p.id
 where spv.ordering = 1
 group by p.id
 order by spv.price_sale  asc
```

i think it gives the result what you want